# jna Native.LoadLibrary does not manage to load library on server (working in local)

Tags: java, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror, jna

I use JNA to load a c++ library (.so) in a java project. I package my library inside the jar, and load it from the jar when instantiating the java class that uses it. I do all this like so:

- mvn install compiles the c++ code and packages the outcome dynamic library inside the jar.
- I call in a static context when instantiating the LibraryWrapperClass  the following

  ```
  System.load( temp.getAbsolutePath() );
  ```

where `temp` is a temporary file containing the library which was found in the jar. This code is based on the work found here [adamheinrich](https://github.com/adamheinrich/native-utils)
- I call `Native.loadLibrary(LIBRARYPATH)` to wrap the library into a java class.

```
    private interface Wrapper extends Library {
        Wrapper INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary( C_LIBRARY_PATH, Wrapper.class );

        Pointer Constructor();
        ...
    }
```

- I run tests and validate that the library was found and up and running.
- I use a java web project that depends on this project. It uses tomcat and runs fine in local.

My issue is that when I deploy on the server, the LibraryWrapperClass cannot instantiate. Error on server is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class pacakgeName.LibraryWrapperClass
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.util.StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.classForName(StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl$4.classForName(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:758)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.classForName(JavaReflectionManager.java:144)
    at...
```

This error seems that the library is found, since there is not the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception thrown. But something else is failing. Do someone know what could happen? How could I debug?

I recall that everything works perfectly in local.

Comment: I assume `pacakgeName` is just a type, right?

Comment: I did not want to disclose the exact package name since it contains private information.

Comment: It doesn't behave differently, of course. The only things that are different are the effective paths.

Comment: So you mean that the library is not found? How can I suggest to have it look at the right location? And how can I prove your point is the one causing my troubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I debug?

**1. with strace**

strace will give you what files Tomcat is trying to open : `strace -f -e trace=file -o log.txt bin/startup.sh`

After this, look for packageName in log.txt, or other files not found with :

```
egrep ' open.*No such file' log.txt
```

**2. with JConsole**

Enable JMX, launch a JConsole, go to VM summary tab, and check/compare very carefully VM arguments/classpath/library path/boot class path

**3. dependency listing with ldd**

If a dependency issue is likely to be the problem, the `ldd sharedLibraryFile.so` command lists all the dependencies and allows to track which one might be missing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is strange because the package name is not appearing in the log. I don't even feel this log contains any error, although I am not sure on how to interpret the log. And the c++ libc.so.6 is found together with g++.

Comment: I believe that the library is found but that a dependency is missing. I do not know how to spot it...

Comment: @EJP said you have different paths, this would lead to file not founds that strace is able to exactly see. I would do  egrep ' open.*No such file' log.txt to find out what files were not found

Comment: If I do `grep ' open.*' log.txt` then I see that all the files that are not found first finish to be found in an alternative directory. And none refer to a path I provided. Thanks

Comment: We'll get a headache with your story. Something must be different between your environments or it would work. You are running Tomcat, right ? Enable JMX, launch a JConsole, go to VM summary tab, and check/compare very carefully VM arguments/classpath/library path/boot class path

Comment: I will edit my answer now, to add reference to JConsole, ok ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167186/discussion-between-eugene-adell-and-yvus).

Comment: Option 3 was the solution to my problem. Thanks

Comment: You're wellcome @Yvus. This was a challenging and exciting troubleshooting ;)

Comment: btw @Yvus I left a comment in the discussion.